# Telegram is having internal issues RpcCallFailError

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to get the latest message from a telegram channel with telethon and the following code:

```
import t_api,time,asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
async def get_message():
    license_b="allow"
    flag=0
    try:
        async with TelegramClient(t_api.username,t_api.api_id,t_api.api_hash) as client:
            my_channel=await client.get_entity("channel_name")
            while license_b=="allow":
                history=await client(GetHistoryRequest(peer=my_channel,offset_id=0,offset_date=None,add_offset=0,limit=1,max_id=0,min_id=0,hash=0))
                t1=history.messages[0].message
                if flag==0:
                    sub_t1=t1
                    flag+=1
                if sub_t1!=t1:
                    flag=0
                    checking_b(t1)
                time.sleep(2)
    except:
        return False
asyncio.run(get_message())
```

I have to use this method due to the delay of about 30 seconds in receiving messages via streaming channels with many members.
And this code works well, but sometimes after a few hours, despite the try except function, program gets following error.

```
Telegram is having internal issues RpcCallFailError: Telegram is having internal issues, please try again later. (caused by GetHistoryRequest)
```

My question is how to prevent this error from occurring and how to handle it if it occurs, because try except dose not work.
Someone can help me?

Comment: You cannot prevent this error. The Telegram servers are having issues. The only thing you can do is wait.

Comment: a small advice, use `await asyncio.sleep(2)` instead of `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: @Lonami Thanks for the reply. But according to this [link](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/276), these problems of the Telegram server have not been solved after more than three years. There must be at least one solution to handle this error or a quick alternative way.

Comment: @NH connectivity issues because the servers are not working properly are sporadic issues. They appear every now and then but often don't last for long, unless the outage is serious.

Answer (score 0):

This is happened bcz you use time.sleep(2) directly. instead use this

```
import asyncio

await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Hope it solve the problem.

The Best option is no need to use sleep...